# Pasar a String contenido de un EditText

Tags: android, edittext

Estoy intentando comparar el texto de una etiqueta con el escrito en un campo de texto, en Android Studio, en concreto un TextView y un EditText, os explico:

```
    if (etInfinitivo.getText().toString().equals(tvVTE.getText().toString()))
    {
        tvVTE.setText("correcto");
    }
```

Donde las variables corresponden a:

```
TextView tvVTE = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtVTE);
EditText etInfinitivo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtInfinitivo);
```

Pues bien, ejecuto la aplicación, copio el contenido de la etiqueta (txtVTE) en la caja de texto (txtInfinitivo) y al pulsar el botón, y llegar al primer código que os he expuesto, el if no se ejecuta, las dos cadenas no son iguales.

¿Se os ocurre a qué puede deberse?

Comment: trata de hacer un trim en la comparacion para eliminar posibles espacios en blanco. que te muestran las cadenas en el depurador ?

Comment: José los 2 textos son iguales ya los comparaste?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que todo, el dato que se encuentra dentro del `EditText` no sera tomado hasta que el evento del `Button` lo ordene. Para que funcione, debes hacerlo dentro del evento `setOnClickListener` del `Button` que tienes ya instanciado.

**Ejemplo:**

```
TextView tvVTE = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtVTE);
EditText etInfinitivo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtInfinitivo);

Mibtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { 

            String palabra1 = tvVTE.getText().toString().trim();
            String palabra2 = etInfinitivo.getText().toString().trim();

            if (palabra1.equalsIgnoreCase(palabra2)) {
                tvVTE.setText("correcto");
            } else {

            }
        }
    });
```

**PD:** La propiedad `equalsIgnoreCase` como lo dice su nombre, permite ignorar las **MAYÚSCULAS** y **minúsculas**.

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar. Había dos problemas en el código:
1. Efectivamente, debía inicializar el EditText en el evento del botón.
2. En la clase que usaba como modelo había un error en el código, estaba comparando dos string mediante "==". Al hacerlo mediante equal ha funcionado todo...

Muchas gracias

Comment: No es nada, no olvides publicar cualquier duda que tengas, Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

**Si los textos son iguales tanto en el `TextView` como en el `EditText` , no debe existir problema al realizar la comparación.**

```
   if (etInfinitivo.getText().toString().equals(tvVTE.getText().toString()))
    {
        tvVTE.setText("correcto");
    }
```

Pero imagina que agregaste un espacio o que en alguna de las vistas introdujiste una letra mayúscula o minúscula diferente a el otro texto!.

Te sugiero usar 2 métodos para evitar este tipo de problemas:

> [trim()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) Devuelve una copia de la cadena, con el espacio en blanco
>   inicial y final omitido.

y

> [toLowerCase()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase()) Convierte todos los caracteres de esta Cadena en
>   minúsculas utilizando las reglas de la configuración regional
>   predeterminada.

Ahora aplicalos a tu sentencia `if` :

```
   if (etInfinitivo.getText().toString().equals(tvVTE.getText().toString()))
    {
        tvVTE.setText("correcto");
    }
```

de esta forma evitaras espacios en blanco o caracteres que sean mayusculas o minusculas en la comparación.